# Is $WIF an NFT or a spl token?

Tags: metaplex, nft, token

I was looking at $WIF on the block explorers with the goal of determining whether it has a fixed supply, normally I thought block explorers would mention the mint/freeze authority and such, however I came across the following metaplex token metadata instead:

```
"root":{12 items
"key":int4
"updateAuthority":string"wifq4CRwpXCK8NYtKNsQAYoDethT1aR7R1DaKCLFgAd"
"mint":string"EKpQGSJtjMFqKZ9KQanSqYXRcF8fBopzLHYxdM65zcjm"
"data":{4 items
"name":string"dogwifhat"
"symbol":string"$WIF"
"uri":string"https://bafkreihwqhounu3cdwgvk2gc2dqcinpntlccbo3xcy4xuerd24yndldl5q.ipfs.nftstorage.link"
"sellerFeeBasisPoints":int0
}
"primarySaleHappened":int0
"isMutable":int0
"editionNonce":int254
"tokenStandard":int2
"name":string"dogwifhat"
"symbol":string"$WIF"
"description":string"Popular meme Dogwifhat vibes wif frens onchain @Dogwifcoin on X"
"image":string"https://bafkreibk3covs5ltyqxa272uodhculbr6kea6betidfwy3ajsav2vjzyum.ipfs.nftstorage.link"
}
```

Which got me confused, for one I thought metaplex was a library for deploying NFTs, so I was surprised to see it associated with what I'm assuming is a token. I mean its definitely a token, since its owned by the token program, but I guess so are NFTs?

My question first and foremost,

1. is $WIF a token or a NFT?
2. is there a mint authority present for $WIF?
3. is the supply capped? or can more tokens technically be minted?

Comment: So after doing some digging around, I stumbled across this in the metaplex docs: 

https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata


So according to the docs, token-metadata can be added for both fungible and non-fungible tokens

Comment: Feel free to put this as the answer and accept it -- it's correct!